# STM32 UART : HAL_UART_Transmit_IT Not working with Task

Tags: stm32, uart

My UART tx Working with blocking mode and before FreeRtoss kernel start. But if I try to transmit inside task Not working( see below code ). Is any special code needed ?

```
enter code here
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, hi, sizeof(hi));
    osDelay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash? Doesn't it produce any output? Please also show the code for your UART interrupt handler.

Comment: Have you enabled the NVIC USART IRQ before starting the task?